# Stored procedure for table search without cycles or cursors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, relational-division

I have a view `vwValues` in my SQL Server 2008 database with these columns:

```
ExamObjID (uniqueidentifier)
Locus (varchar(10))
ValOrder (tinyint)
Value (varchar(5))
IndexType (char(1))
PersCount (tinyint))
```

and sample data like this:

| ExamObjID | Locus | ValOrder | Value | IndexType | PersCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f9576b7b-20a1-4d63-8c80-b8ffd68aefc5 | L1T1234 | 1 | 12 | C | 1 |
| f9576b7b-20a1-4d63-8c80-b8ffd68aefc5 | L1T1234 | 2 | 12 | C | 1 |
| f9576b7b-20a1-4d63-8c80-b8ffd68aefc5 | L2T54332 | 1 | 14 | C | 1 |
| f9576b7b-20a1-4d63-8c80-b8ffd68aefc5 | L2T54332 | 2 | 15 | C | 1 |
| f9576b7b-20a1-4d63-8c80-b8ffd68aefc5 | L3R12 | 1 | 11 | C | 1 |
| f9576b7b-20a1-4d63-8c80-b8ffd68aefc5 | L3R12 | 2 | 17 | C | 1 |

So for any `ExamObjID` there is anywhere between 6 and 27 `Locus` each with up to 4 `Value`'s (and respective `ValOrder` enumerating that `Value`'s ). Also one `ExamObjID` can have only one distinct `IndexType` and `PersCount`.

The database also has a stored procedure that accepts specific `ExamObjID` , builds a table variable `@Target` with the same structure as `vwValues` view (omiting IndexType and PersCount columns) and populates it with all entries from this view that have such `ExamObjID` .

Now what it makes is selects other `ExamObjID` 's from the view, starts some rather cumbersome cursor that calls for scalar functions - all to compare the `@target` table to every other `ExamObjID` in view that has `PersCount = 1` .

The comparison terms are: the two `ExamObjID` 's are considered a "match" if they have at least 6 identical `Locus` and in every (exept for maximum 2) identical `Locus` they have at least 1 identical `Value`.

Every "matching" `ExamObject` is written into `SearchResults` Table `(SearchResultID uniqueidentifier, ExamObjID uniqueidentifier, MatchObjID uniqueidentifier, MisMatchCount (tinyint))` and then the cursor moves on to the next `ExamObjID` in the view. MisMatchCount column stores the quantity of Locus that mismathed during comparison so it stores values between 0 and 2.

Needless to say all this scheme is **very slow** and for a DB that has hundreds of thousands ID's it can take anywhere around 15 minutes per one search.

So the question is: is there any way to replace all this "cursors and scalar functions" part with some neat cycleless code block? I am nowhere around being a professional coder but really want to improve this part to reduce search times. Will be very grateful for any tips and ideas. Also I do not really know if it is even possible to achieve so please tell me it is impossible and I will search for another ways to improve the situation.

UPD[1]: more about matching rules.

Per-Locus match:
this Locus of ExamObjID f9576b7b-20a1-4d63-8c80-b8ffd68aefc5 :

| ExamObjID | Locus | ValOrder | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f9576b7b-20a1-4d63-8c80-b8ffd68aefc5 | L1T1234 | 1 | 12 |
| f9576b7b-20a1-4d63-8c80-b8ffd68aefc5 | L1T1234 | 2 | 14 |

is considered a match with this Locus of ExamObjID e1185832-a6b7-4b08-913c-fb75be0f8588:

| ExamObjID | Locus | ValOrder | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e1185832-a6b7-4b08-913c-fb75be0f8588 | L1T1234 | 1 | 14 |
| e1185832-a6b7-4b08-913c-fb75be0f8588 | L1T1234 | 2 | 15 |

because they share at least one common Value = 14.

Per-ExamObjID match: all common Locus in two ExamObjID must match with exception of maximum 2 Locus'es.

UPD[2]:
tried to create a snippet that simulates new stored procedure. still doing something wrong, it just returns all other ExamObjects from the database like they have 0 mismatches.

```
DECLARE @ExamObjID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '62DA5C53-E70A-473A-923B-388232B79AFF'
DECLARE @Target TABLE (
    ExamObjID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    Locus VARCHAR(15),
    Value VARCHAR(5)
);
DECLARE @Result TABLE (ExamObjID uniqueidentifier, MismatchCount tinyint);

INSERT INTO @Target 
    SELECT ExamObjID, Locus, Value FROM vwValues WHERE ExamObjID = @ExamObjID;

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT a.ExamObjID, 
           COUNT(CASE WHEN b.value = a.value THEN 1 END) AS Matches, 
           COUNT(CASE WHEN b.value <> a.value THEN 1 END) AS Mismatches
    INTO #temp
    FROM vwValues a
    INNER JOIN @Target b
    ON a.Locus = b.Locus AND a.value = b.value AND a.ExamObjID <> b.ExamObjID
    GROUP BY a.ExamObjID
    
    INSERT INTO @Result(ExamObjID, MismatchCount)
    SELECT ExamObjID, Mismatches
    FROM #temp
    WHERE Matches >= 6 AND Mismatches <= 2;
    
    DROP TABLE #temp;
    SELECT * FROM @Result
END
```

UPD[3]:
More on per-`ExamObjID` match and "common `locus`'es" between 2 `ExamObject`s.
Assume we have 2 ExamObjects in vwValues with 2 different ExamObjID's. Those ExamObjID's are `uniqueidentifier`s, but lets assume they are stored in `@Id1` and `@Id2` variables.
Query `SELECT DISTINCT Locus FROM vwValues WHERE ExamObjID = @Id1` returns a list:
`L1T1234, L2T54332, L3R12, L4R4, L5RTdev`
while query `SELECT DISTINCT Locus FROM vwValue WHERE ExamObjID = @Id2` returns a list: `L3R12,L4R4,L5RTdev,L6T10,L7indel,L8cascade`
So there are three `Locus`'es that are **common** for `@Id1` and `@Id2`: `L3R12,L4R4,L5RTdev`. Only data for those 3 `Locus` is relevant when comparing `ExamObjID`'s data. In real database every `ExamObjID` has anywhere from 8 to 27 distinct `Locus` and the search algorythm must assume that to compare data for 2 `ExamObjID`'s they must have at least 6 common distinct `Locus`.
So the fact that 2 `ExamObjID`'s have at least 6 **common** `Locus` is a requirement for their comparison to begin to establish if they can be a **match**.
Now about the matching rules. For every **common** `Locus` for two `ExamObjID`'s we compare there must be at least 1 identical `Value`. The example  of 2 matching `Locus` provided previously in the section "UPD[1]" of this post. Exeption can be for at most two **common** `Locus`, meaning that if two `ExamObject`s have 10 common `Locus` at least 8 of that `Locus` must match.
If any matching `ExamObjID`'s were found, the procedure stores this result in a table `SearchResults` with columns

```
ExamObjID uniqueidentifier, -- target ExamObjID
MatchObjID uniqueidentifier, -- Matching ExamObjID,
MisMatchCnt tinyint -- number of mismatched common Locus
```

Also there is a script with schema and data for a tiny database I made for testing purpose. There are 10 distinct ExamObjects that have either identical or slightly different values in common Loci.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17omKglwPCbjvqmT1UYRkt-izi3ykQoOy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you provide the code you have, along with  sample data and expected result this would be much easier for us to help you. Though, as you are using a long unsupported version of SQL Server, that will only be detrimental to a *good* solution; SQL Server 2008 lacks *a lot* of functionality that recent versions have that can be taken for granted.

Comment: @ThomA The code I have in the DB is a really big and messy amalgam of cursors inside the cursors and functions called from inside them. Have no idea if I can even post such a big chunks of code.. But sure I will add better explanation of sample and resulting data to original post.

Comment: The usual "improvement" in a case like this would be to write a query rather than use a cursor. But your requirements are complex. I think you need to provide more test data as well, in order to be able to work up a solution. Also, since this is based on a view, perhaps the view is part of the problem (i.e., maybe it is not good to use this view in this case).

Comment: @ThomA also I need to say that the usage of SQL Server 2008 is a hard requirement since our facilities management refuses any upgrades (no real idea why).

Comment: @topsail in fact the usage of a view was an improvement since it replaces previously existant queries that retrieved data from multiple tables. It helped to speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: *"our facilities management refuses any upgrade"* this is, honestly, a terrible stance. 20008 ran out of support *completely* in 2019; it has been *almost* **4 years** since it received*any* security updates. Using such an instance is a *huge* security risk.

Comment: *the usage of a view was an improvement since it replaces previously existant queries that retrieved data from multiple tables* I'll take your word for it but "retrieving data from multiple tables" is not something that views do better than queries (because, well, queries and view both can retrieve data from multiple tables - that's basically just what queries and views are). More likely you had bad queries and need good ones (and in any case sounds like you still need more improvement so don't rule out possibilities).

Comment: Can you show some examples where this `all common Locus in two ExamObjID must match with exception of maximum 2 Locus'es.` applies. I.e., cases with 0, 1, 2 and 3 matches - how does it work?

Comment: @topsail sure. Added more info in section "UPD[3]" of the original post. Please tell me if there is any more explanation I can provide.

Comment: @ThomA Not *quite* true, it got an update for a very serious security flaw last month https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5021112-description-of-the-security-update-for-sql-server-2008-r2-sp3-gdr-february-14-2023-844419ed-d837-467f-97e8-eed2e281c40c and another few flaws back in 2018 but otherwise not since 2016.

Comment: That is provided you have subscribed to the Extended Security updates, @Charlieface ; which would also mean the OP has paid 3.5 times the cost (iirc) of the initial licence fee on the last 3 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can do this all in one query.**

This is a type of query called **[Relational Division With Remainder](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)**, with the added tweak that you want certain conditions per divided set.

I would advise, given that you appear to be querying from a view, to put the divisor (the *Target*) into a table variable that has a primary key. In some situations you can just combine the first `SELECT` below directly into the second.

```sql
DECLARE @ExamObjID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '62DA5C53-E70A-473A-923B-388232B79AFF'
DECLARE @Target TABLE (
    ExamObjID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    Locus VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Value VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Locus, ExamObjID, Value)
);

INSERT INTO @Target (ExamObjID, Locus, Value)
SELECT ExamObjID, Locus, Value
FROM vwValues
WHERE ExamObjID = @ExamObjID;

SELECT
  other.ExamObjID,
  Mismatches = COUNT(CASE WHEN other.Matches = 0 THEN 1 END)
FROM (
    SELECT
      other.ExamObjID,
      other.Locus,
      Matches = COUNT(CASE WHEN other.Value = t.Value THEN 1 END)
    FROM vwValues other
    JOIN @Target t ON t.Locus = other.Locus
    WHERE t.ExamObjID <> other.ExamObjID
    GROUP BY
      other.ExamObjID,
      other.Locus
) other
GROUP BY
  other.ExamObjID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 6
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN other.Matches = 0 THEN 1 END) <= 2;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/zR7HgRPc)

The logic is as follows:

- Within a derived subquery, join the target set with the rest of the table (excluding itself) joined only by `Locus`.
- Group by both `ExamObjID` and `Locus`, taking a count of rows which match by `Value`.
- Group again on the outside just by `ExamObjID`
- Exclude any groups which have less than 6 rows ie per `Locus`...
- ... and any which have their number of "rows that have no matches" more than 2
- Finally output the `ExamObjID` along with that number of mismatches.

Comment: Thenk you. This works perfectly with time reduction of performing a regular search from 10-15  minutes to just around 5 seconds.
Also thank you for an explanation and reference information on this type of queries. I shall rework some other procedures of this kind and am excited to try my best.